# Data Migration Tool [Connection refused] from AWS to Local dockerized enviroment

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, aws, data-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate my Magento 1 data from a DB located in AWS, to a Magento 2 in a local dockerized enviroment.

When I run

```
bin/magento migrate:settings -a -r -vvv app/code/Mymodules/Migration/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.10/config.xml
```

The connection is refused

```
[PDOException (2002)] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I've already opened the 3306 port to my local adding a Inbound rule to the Security Group, like this:

```
MYSQL/Aurora | TPC | 3306 | MYIPADDRESS/32 | My description
```

**Questions**

- I'm using the Magento's non-root MySQL credentials, so remote
  connection should allowed right?
- What else could be blocking the connection?
- Is it possible to connect Data Migration Tool to a remote DB using a SSH Tunnel?

**Extra details**

If I try to connect from my terminal this way, the connection is also    refused:

```
mysql -hxx.xxx.xx.xx -p3306 -umyuser -pmypassword
```

Here's my config.xml details:

```
...
    <source>
        <database host="xx.xxx.xx.xx" port="3306" name="mydb" user="myuser" password="mypassword" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="127.0.0.1" name="magento" user="magento" password="magento" />
    </destination>
    <options>
        <crypt_key>mymagento1key</crypt_key>
    </options>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the Inbound Rule to open the port 3306 is not being taken into consideration.

The only solution which work for me was my `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` file and addding the ip address to `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` line.

Then, I had to restart mysql: `sudo systemctl restart mysql.service`

Now I'm able to connect to the DB remotely from my IP.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using the Magento's non-root MySQL credentials, so remote
>   connection should allowed right?

Yes remote connection should work if correctly opened on Amazon Web Services, I had to ensure the same thing on Azure.

Regarding your issue for running `mysql -u`, you have the incorrect switch for Port.  You need to confirm if you are able to access the database server remotely first before attempting to migrate.

It is supposed to be **`-P`**, **`-p`** is only for *password*.

`mysql -u username -p -h hostname -P 3306`

(I have done a recent remote data migration from Azure hosted Database Magento 1.7 to Magento 2.3.5 (local) by firstly confirming the remote host and ports)

Comment: Same result. Removing the Port parameter o using -P as uppercase. 3306 should be the default port.

Comment: In your question you specified port 3006:

`mysql -hxx.xxx.xx.xx -p3006 -umyuser -pmypassword`

Is this correct (as in AWS configured it from **3306** to **3006**?)

Comment: The right port is 3306, sorry.

Comment: I do not see any way to connect using the data-migration-tool via `ssh` as you were asking originally.  It is possible that somewhere in the AWS configuration the database port is not 'opened' to the outside if you aren't able to access it via `mysql -u`.  In Azure you specifically have to configure it through the firewall.